# A better way to write arrow symbol with words above and under it?

Tags: syntax

I'm a daily math.se user and I've read about the [tutorial page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) but I haven't seen, for me, a simple/shorter way to re-write the following symbol

[image: arrow with above/under-words]

The mathjax syntax I used is: `$\overset{linear}{\underset{invertible}\longrightarrow}$`.

Requirements:

1. Shorter.
2. Is it possible to have a nice look one like
   [image: better version]
   s.t. the arrow is longer and its length is approximately equal to max{above-text, below-text}? (The red verticals are not needed in result, it's for visualization what I mean about max{a,b}.)
3. I don't know any macro/package/framework but they're ok if you could teach me how to import it in a beginner-friendly way.

Comment: Are you looking for a Mathjax solution? Because this site is about TeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Load `mathtools` and do `$A\xrightarrow[invertible]{linear}B$`, but more correct would be  `$A\xrightarrow[\mathrm{invertible}]{\mathrm{linear}}B$`.

Comment: @Milo: No, any solution is ok. But if this can be done in pure Mathjax I will be happy.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
$A\xrightarrow[\mathrm{invertible}]{\mathrm{linear}}B$
\end{document}`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was solved in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

From @marmot's comment:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\begin{document} 
$A\xrightarrow[\mathrm{invertible}]{\mathrm{linear}}B$ 
\end{document}
```

The version that can be used on math.se: `$A\xrightarrow[invertible]{linear}B$`.